# Ruby instance attribute somehow being set to `true` instead of the intended value upon another attributes modification

Tags: ruby

Learning oop in Ruby and encountering some unexpected behavior in a class i've written. Here is my Radio class, I can change the volume attribute, but when I change the freq attribute, the band attribute is changed from fm to true. I cannot figure out why this is happening.

my file init.rb that's calling the Radio class:

```
require_relative 'classes/radio'
fm_radio = Radio.fm
fm_radio.volume = 10
puts fm_radio.status
#volume: 10 band: fm frequency: 88.0

fm_radio.freq = 99.0
puts fm_radio.status
#volume: 10 band: true frequency: 99.0
puts fm_radio.band
# true
```

my file radio.rb that contains the Radio class:

```
class Radio
    attr_accessor :volume, :freq
    attr_reader :band

    def initialize(band)
        @band = band
        if band == 'am'
            @freq = 540.0
        else
            @freq = 88.0
        end
        @volume = 1
    end

    def volume=(value)
        return if value < 1 || value > 10
        @volume = value
    end

    def freq=(value)
        if @band = 'am' && (540.0..1600).include?(value)
            @freq = value
        elsif @band = 'fm' && (88.0..108.0).include?(value)
            @freq = value
        else
            puts 'out of range'
        end
    end

    def crank_it_up
        @volume = 11
    end

    def status 
        "volume: #{@volume} band: #{@band} frequency: #{@freq}"
    end

    def self.am 
        Radio.new('am')
    end

    def self.fm 
        Radio.new('fm')
    end
end
```

Comment: In `initialize` I might suggest `@freq = band == 'am' ? 540.0 : 88.0` to both more concisely and more clearly express this.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in these two lines:

```
    if @band = 'am' && (540.0..1600).include?(value)
    elsif @band = 'fm' && (88.0..108.0).include?(value)
```

Using a single `=`, you're assigning to `@band` what is evaluated from `'am' && (540.0..1600).include?(value)`, which eventually will be a boolean value.
You must use `==` to compare `@band` with another string.